# calling function using its name as a string and using replacing parameters with an array

Tags: javascript, string, function, parameters, eval

Here is my example for better understanding of my question. lets say:

```
var a = ["Hello", "World"];
var b = "Hi";
```

How can I do:

```
console.log(b."concat"(a)); // and return HiHelloWorld
```

I tried doing this:

```
console.log(b.eval("concat").apply(this, a));
```

but it gives me an error saying that b.eval is not a function.
Please note that my primary goal is not to concatenate strings. This is just an example. I want to be able to do this with any function...

Thank You

Comment: You seem to be looking for `b["concat"].apply(b, a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `[]` syntax together with the spread operator `...`.

```js
var a = ["Hello", "World"];
var b = "Hi";

console.log(b["concat"](...a));
```

Comment: why is there a comma between Hello and World?

Comment: i am new to javascript. can you please explain to me whats the use of adding (...)?

Comment: It converts `fun([a,b,c])` into `fun(a,b,c)`

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked like a charm. much appreciated